# In a cycle for git add / rebase --continue

Tags: git, rebase

There is a file that had a modify (local)/delete (remote) conflict that was exposed during

```
git rebase

CONFLICT (modify/delete): python/pyspark/hbase.py deleted in HEAD and modified in Python support. Version Python support of python/pyspark/hbase.py left in tree.
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 Python support
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /shared/hwspark/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
```

I did a  git rm -f on the file

```
git rm  -f python/pyspark/hbase.py
```

Now git says all merge conflicts resolved.

```
$git status
rebase in progress; onto a153ab6
You are currently rebasing branch 'hbase' on 'a153ab6'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
```

However when we "follow the directions":

```
$git rebase --continue
Applying: Python support
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

So what should be done to clean this up?

Comment: Usually, `git rebase --skip`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
>   already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this
>   patch.

As the message suggests, you want to do `git rebase --skip` now.